# Reading specific lines from an external file in ruby IO

Tags: ruby, io

I have this code:

```
File.foreach("testfile.txt") { |line| print line }
lines = File.readlines("testfile.txt")
lines.each { |line| print line }
```

Ex. how could I edit this to **get** a specific line from `testfile.txt` ?

```
$text2 = gets("some code to give me text on line 2 from textfile.txt").chomp
```

So, I want to run a program that searches for 4 different variables that are editable by anyone. These will be in a separate file and thus the code will not have to be rewritten in order to change the test for a new set of search cases.

Say I have a document (I suppose text is easiest but am probably wrong) that looks like this:

```
Tea

Coffee

Hot Chocolate

Cookies
```

That will be all that is in the file. And another file(.rb) pulls these variables and searches for them in Google or whatever. If the code reads in bytes then I wouldn't be able to change the variables to anything longer or shorter.

It would be feasible to have the document say

```
1:Tea

2:Coffee

3:Hot Chocolate

4:Cookies
```

So long as the code would only pull out the "Tea" or "coffee" and not the preceding number.

Comment: Avoid using `$` global variable as far as I know that's considered to be Bad Practice in Ruby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want to return a line that matches a certain pattern, but you want to grab by line number.

Solution 1:

```
def read_line_number(filename, number)
  return nil if number < 1
  line = File.readlines(filename)[number-1]
  line ? line.chomp : nil
end
```

Solution 2a - a bit more efficient because it doesn't try to read entire file:

```
require 'english'
def read_line_number_1a(filename, number)
  found_line = nil
  File.foreach(filename) do |line|
    if $INPUT_LINE_NUMBER == number
      found_line = line.chomp
      break
    end
  end
  found_line
end
```

Solution 2b - also efficient, but in a more functional style (though I haven't checked whether `detect` will read to end-of-file)

```
def read_line_number(filename, match_num)
  found_line, _idx =
    File.enum_for(:foreach, filename).each_with_index.detect do |_cur_line, idx|
      cur_line_num = idx+1
      cur_line_num == match_num
    end
  found_line.chomp
end
```

Usage:

```
text = read_line_number("testfile.txt", 2)
```

Comment: what format would the text file be in for this exact code to work?

Comment: @benjamin-shephard I know that if you're running a native ruby interpreter with a native text file (ie line-endings), it will work fine; e.g. Windows ruby on a Windows (CRLF) text file will work. The code might not work as-is if you're working with Windows text on a Linux system, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use `lines.grep "some string"`.
Or just `lines[x]` if you know exactly which line number `x` you want.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have is:

My testfile.txt reads

Yes 
Yes is does
Man this is awesome

my .rb file reads

`a = IO.readlines("testfile.txt").grep(/\w+/) 

puts "does it work...."

sleep 2

puts a[2]

sleep 10`

Answer (score 0):

```
def read_line_number(filename, number)
f = File.open(filename)
l = nil
begin
  number.times do 
  l = f.readline.chomp
  end
rescue
puts "End of file reached"
else
f.close unless f.nil?
return l  
end
end
```

Comment: sorry about thet :/ .....this code read line X.times so if u want a known line this read till get there and return only the last line read..
btw.. is this efficient?